# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, sockets

I am a beginner in Python Programming with Socket.
Now, I have a problem with this error

```
data, address = s.recvfrom(MAX)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The following is my code:

```
import socket, sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

MAX = 65535
PORT = 1060

a = raw_input()

if a == "server":
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1",PORT))
    print("Listening at ", s.getsockname())
    while True:
        data, address = s.recvfrom(MAX)
        print("The client at " + str(address) + " says " + repr(data))
elif a == "client":
    s.sendto("This is my message".encode(), ("127.0.0.1", PORT))

    print("Address after sending: ", s.getsockname())
    data, address = s.recvfrom(MAX)
    print("The server " + address + " says " + repr(data))
else:
    print(sys.stderr)
```

After I run the program and enter "client" as my input, it cause the error.
Thank you for your answer. ;)

Comment: Will you please inform, why `client` is listening as `server`?  Code : `data, address = s.recvfrom(MAX)`

Comment: I'm not sure. I get this code from a book.
There is a comment in that line said "Overly promiscuous - see text!"

Do you have any suggestion about how to communicate between Server and Client?

Sorry for late replying @Lafada

Comment: Server always receive and client always send. I dont know in book why they receive in client. For code its working for me. Please try again with this changes. Check that when you enter 'server` it listen on port.

Comment: I just got the solution that Server and Client must run in the same time. Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry for late replying. ;) @Lafada

Comment: @PandarianLd Servers and clients both send and receive. There is no listening here. Your question doesn't make sense,

Comment: @Nilesh 'Servers always receive and clients always send' is a considerable overstatement. There is no clear distinction in UDP.

Answer (score -1):

Run the server and client on same time :)